# How can I convince postfix to send mail to my local maildir using dovecot lmtr?

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot

I have installed dovecot and postfix on debian 12 and it is working but broken.
I can connect to dovecot and see the existence of /var/mail/username/ on my server.
My problem is simply that sending mail to myself does not work.
When I do this:

```
username@node12 (~ ): mail username -s "$(date)" 
Cc: 
blah
 ^D
```

I see this in the logs:

```
Mar 07 11:32:21 node12.xxxx.net postfix/lmtp[447029]: 8B248219AE: to=<username@node12.xxxx.net>, relay=node12.xxxx.net[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host node12.xxxx.net[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 550 5.1.1 <username@node12.xxxx.net> User doesn't exist: username@node12.xxxx.net (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

You can see that the name "username" was changed to "username@node12.xxxx.net", which I guess might be the problem.  But I'm not sure.
How can I persuade postfix and dovecot to just send the mail to /var/mail/username in maildir format, i.e. using dovecot-lmtp?
Is this a MySQL tables issue, or is it something in postfix/main.cf, or perhaps in dovecot/dovecot.conf?
I'm overwhelmed...
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

OK I sorted it out.  First, I added user 'username@node12.xxxx.net' to my virtual_users table.  This seems to allow things to proceed somehow.

```
MariaDB [mailserver]> INSERT INTO mailserver.virtual_users (domain_id, password , email) VALUES ('2', '$6$27Ebj25gWwL2ewmr$A.DX6LgDVExbpnVJPxB38G1.lV/p4vtDGhDa1sRYpZN5LlIyyqnK2WA748ejyQjXU4auxFE5JkN7DZsNUV.bA1', 'username@node12.xxxx.net');
```

And then I chased down some permissions problems that showed up in the logs.

```bash
root@node12 (postfix ): chgrp -R dovecot /var/mail/username
chmod 1775 (all folders in /var/mail/username)
chmod 664 all files in /var/mail/username
```

And it is now working.  Whew.  I'm just going to leave this here in case it helps someone else later.

Comment: This is exactly how you should contribute to this community! +1